# Import word documents with quanteda

Tags: quanteda, .doc

Hello I'm not succeding in importing word documents quanteda. I'm using this command

my_texts <- readtext::readtext("~/Users/grouetl/Documents/ProjetsLISE/Boimondau/Transcriptionstribunal/.doc*")

and get this error message:

Error in list_files(file, ignore_missing, TRUE, verbosity) :
File '' does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your wildcard expression is wrong.

Try this in the Terminal:

```bash
ls ~/Users/grouetl/Documents/ProjetsLISE/Boimondau/Transcriptionstribunal/.doc*
```

If nothing results, then your pattern is wrong.

I would suggest you try:

```r
readtext("~/Users/grouetl/Documents/ProjetsLISE/Boimondau/Transcriptionstribunal/*.doc*")
```

Comment: Thanks but with boteh expressions i get the same error message  : "Error in list_files(file, ignore_missing, TRUE, verbosity) : 
  File '' does not exist."

Comment: I took a shot in the dark but without having access to a reproducible example, no one is going to be able to solve your issue.

Comment: i'm using tm package to import files and it works fine..

Answer (score 0):

I tried both was and also changed my files to txt but I always get the same result. I go back to tm package to import my files ..